# Can someone please explain this Twisted unit test?

Tags: python, twisted.web

I just inherited some unit tests around Twisted Python, as shown below.

While the test works, I don't understand it conceptually.

Given the example below, can someone please explain the following things about it?

- Why does this unit test 'return page'?
- Why aren't there any calls to reactor.start()?
- Any comments about the pros/cons of this approach, and perhaps others I could consider?

---

```
def setUp(self):
    self.listening_port = reactor.listenTCP(8118, server.Site(buildSite()))        

def tearDown(self):
    self.listening_port.stopListening()

def getUrl(self, extension=''):
    return 'http://localhost:%s/%s' % (self.listening_port.getHost().port, extension)

 def test(self):
     url = self.getUrl('foo')        
     def printResult(result):
         print result        
     page = getPage(url, method='POST').addCallback(printResult)
     return page
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Why does this unit test 'return page'?*

Well, it's not very clean. Twisted's Trial unittest expect Deferred as result, with assert as callback. Here the callback is `printResult`, thus it will be evaluated to true for any non-empty string. I think more properly it should be:

```
page = getPage(url, method='POST').addCallback(self.assertTrue)
```

or

```
page = getPage(url, method='POST').addCallback(self.assertIsNotNone)
```

> *Why aren't there any calls to reactor.start()?*

Because `TestCase` class takes care of that. And it's also not using standard reactor.

> Since unit tests are avoiding real I/O and real time, they can usually
>   avoid using a real reactor. The only exceptions to this are unit tests
>   for a real reactor implementation. Unit tests for protocol
>   implementations or other application code should not use a reactor.
>   Unit tests for real reactor implementations should not use the global
>   reactor, but should instead use
>   twisted.internet.test.reactormixins.ReactorBuilder so they can be
>   applied to all of the reactor implementations automatically. In no
>   case should new unit tests use the global reactor.